# Get SharePoint user from WebApi2 Identity

Tags: csom, user, credentials, webapi

I have a WebApi2 endpoint where `supportCredentials` flag is set to true. On the IIS the `Anonymous Authentication` on false and the `Windows Authentication` on true.

What I'm trying to do is to load the right ShatePoint user based on the Identity loaded in `RequestContext.Principal.Identity`.

Current code:

```
string userLogin = RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(WebConfig.Portal))
{
    List list = ctx.Site.RootWeb.SiteUserInfoList;

    var caml = new CamlQuery
    {
        ViewXml = $"<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Name'/><Value Type='Text'>{userLogin}</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>"
    };

    var users = list.GetItems(caml);
    ctx.Load(users);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    IEnumerable<ListItem> user = from u in users.Cast<ListItem>()
                orderby u.Id descending
                select u;

    return Convert.ToString(user.First()["EMail"]);
}
```

It works, but I don't really like it. My first approach was:

```
string userLogin = RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(WebConfig.Portal))
{
    UserCollection list = ctx.Site.RootWeb.SiteUsers;
    User user = list.GetByLoginName(userLogin);
    ctx.Load(user);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    return user.Email;
}
```

The latter does not always work, since the Identity.Name is like "DOMAIN\USERNAME" but some SharePoint users have e.g the prefix `i:0#.w|` which is not present in the Identity.Name. The idea was to add `i:0#.w|` + userLogin, but as far I've read, this prefix may change.

Is there a clean and working way to load the correct SharePoint user with this Identity information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the login name is in casual domain format DOMAIN\USERNAME, you can convert it to valid SharePoint claims format and getting user using

```
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
//...

// resolve user principal using regular login name or e-mail:
var userPrincipal = SP.Utilities.Utility.ResolvePrincipal(
  context, 
  context.Web, 
  "DOMAIN\\user", // normal login name
  SP.Utilities.PrincipalType.User,
  SP.Utilities.PrincipalSource.All,
  context.Web.SiteUsers,
  false);

context.ExecuteQuery();

// ensure that the user principal was resolved:
if (userPrincipal.Value == null)
  throw new Exception("The specified user principal could not be resolved");

// get a User instance based on the encoded login name from userPrincipal
var user = context.Web.SiteUsers.GetByLoginName(userPrincipal.LoginName);
context.Load(user);

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

On the other hand, simply doing this *might* work for DOMAIN\USERNAME as well, so it's worth a try.

```
var ctx = new ClientContext(site);
var rootWeb = ctx.Site.RootWeb;
var usr = rootWeb.EnsureUser("DOMAIN\\USERNAME");
ctx.Load(usr);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: The first one works as I need. The second one doesn't IF there there is one user `i:0#.w|DOMAIN\USERNAME` and a second one `DOMAIN\USERNAME`. I know that such a state is wrong, but it could be.